# How to select a dictionary attribute based on another attribute's value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list (`term_list`) containing the following:

```py
[
    {
        'taxonomy': 'type', 
        'href': 'https://example.com/1'
    }, {
        'taxonomy': 'status', 
        'href': 'https://example.com/2'
    }, {
        'taxonomy': 'feature', 
        'href': 'https://example.com/3'
    }
]
```

I need to select the `href` of the `"taxonomy":"feature"` BUT it's not guaranteed to be in the same order each time so I can't use list positioning.

**How can I select the value of `href` depending on the value of `taxonomy`?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use list comprehensions:

```
term_list = [
    {
        'taxonomy': 'type',
        'href': 'https://example.com/1'
    }, {
        'taxonomy': 'status',
        'href': 'https://example.com/2'
    }, {
        'taxonomy': 'feature',
        'href': 'https://example.com/3'
    }
]

print([obj['href'] for obj in term_list if obj['taxonomy'] == 'feature'])
```

Ouptut:

```
['https://example.com/3']
```

Comment: So simple. That's exactly what I need and definitely Pythonic. I was just missing how to express it in such a way. Thanks for the super fast answer!

Comment: Is there a way to return it as a string value instead of a list?

Comment: print([obj['href'] for obj in term_list if obj['taxonomy'] == 'feature'][0])